# Failed to minify file main 1.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, npm, runtime-error

I received an error because of this code. Can I ask for some help how to fix this? Thank you.

```
for (const file of data_to_minify) {
  try {
    
      const [error, minifiedContent] = await tryToCatch(minify, file.file.filename, options);

      if (error) {
          console.error(`Failed to minify file ${file.file.filename}: ${error.message}`);
          continue;
      }

      fs.writeFileSync(file.file.filename);

      minifiedFiles.push({
          filename: file.file.filename,
          content: minifiedContent,
          type: file.type
      });
  } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Failed to process file ${file.file.filename}: ${error}`);
  }
}
```

[image: image of error]

Comment: The file or directory doesn't seem to exist?